# How to change SearchBar border color

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

I would like to change grey border color in my `Search Bar` to white color. Now it looks like that:

[image: search bar]

I achieved this effect after using this lines of code, but "inside border" is still grey:

```
var searchBar: UISearchController!

    self.searchBar.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.searchBar.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 3
    self.searchBar.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.searchBar.searchBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.searchBar.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.63, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1)
```

Can somebody help me in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Result of the code below.]

```
self.searchBar.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
self.searchBar.searchBar.translucent = false
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.searchBar.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.searchBar.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Code above will give you all white searchbar but likely there will be black lines at top and bottom of the searchbar as you can see from the attachment. If you see the black lines and if you don't want them, change;

```
self.searchBar.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

with

```
self.searchBar.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "nameOfYourWhiteImage")
```

And you will have a clean white searchbar. Hope this solves your problem. Good luck!

Comment: How do I remove the top and botton line in search bar

Answer (score 6):

You can try `self.searchBar.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal` to get a clean look with white background, no lines at top or bottom and slightly grey inside to see the actual search field.

Comment: Best answer for swift 4+

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 2 handy extensions for that:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func imageFromLayer (layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
        layer.render(in: currentContext)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage
    }
}

extension UISearchBar {
    func setCustomBackgroundColor (color: UIColor) {
        let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
        backgroundLayer.frame = frame
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        if let image = UIImage.imageFromLayer(layer: backgroundLayer) {
            self.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use:

```
self.searchBar.setCustomBackgroundColor (color: UIColor.white)
```